# Using Attributed text in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uitextview

I'm creating a static Getting Started Guide using a UITextView in Interface Builder using .Xib files.

I've added a bunch of formatted text onto here and it looks fine in Interface Builder:

[image]

However when I run it on my iPhone or Simulator I see this:

[image]

Fonts have been added to the plist: 
[image]

[image]

Why is the text not being displayed as I expected it would?

Comment: Did you added fonts to plist?

Comment: Yes, I added the fonts to the plist

Comment: have you set allowsEditingTextAttributes enabled?

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans I found the same issue. Hope you will get answer (Y)

Comment: Are you using any kind of localization in your app? Maybe thats messes up your formatting

Comment: I've tried setting allowsEditingTextAttributes to enabled. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my entire plist. There is some Localization going on but is that the cause of this behavior?

Comment: have you tried setting the font programmatically? This may be a Xcode bug that makes you not able to set the font via IB

Comment: I have not, but I do not only want the font I'm also using 3 different font sizes / styles

Comment: I've tried setting the font programmatically. It doesn't change anything. self.textView.font = UIFont(name: "JohnstonITCProMedium", size: 16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not able to get the UITextView to work so I decided to solve it like this (using a UIWebView and hosting a HTML formatted webpage):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.opaque = false;
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();

    let url = NSURL (string: "https://mysecreturl.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
}
```

Not ideal but it works for now.